Elementary proof of the limit of $n^{n^{-p}}$
I'm going through George Bergman's exercises for Rudin's PMA Chapter 3 (Sequences and Series)  and Bergman asks the following:
Prove or disprove: For every positive real number $p$, one has $\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{n^{-p}} = 1$. (Rudin proves the case for $p = 1$).
One can see this is true using strong theorems, but...
Since this question is in Chapter 3, things not yet introduced shouldn't be used like $\log$, $e$, derivatives, etc. (although Rudin gives a rudi(n)mentary definition of $\log$ in Ch. 1 Exc. 7). The case for $p > 1$ is easy, since $n^{n^{-p}} \leq n^{n^{-1}}$.
But my biggest struggle is when 0 < p < 1.
I've tried copying Rudin by trying to come up with a clever manipulation of binomial theorem, but I have not gotten any insight, since $n^p$ is not necessarily an integer, or even rational. And even when I try to brute-force my way with binomial theorem, it seems that I have to prove an alternative formulation of the same question.
I've tried thinking of an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof, since $n^{-p} \to 0$ as was proven by Rudin. But I think that will require $\log$ since $n^{n^{-p}} = b^{n^{-p}\log_b{n}},\ b > 1$. Maybe Bergman allows this if one has completed Ch. 1 Exc. 7, but he did not say that it was prerequisite.
I've tried thinking of a clever equality/inequality to use here (QM-AM-GM-HM, telescoping, binomial theorem) but the possibility that $n^p$ can be irrational and the sequence can converge extremely slowly seems to nullify the usefulness of many equations.
Perhaps I can show it for $p$, where $p$ is in the range of a sequence converging to $0$ like $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Then choose $n$ large enough and use binomial theorem?

If you know $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log \log n}{\log n} = 0$, then the proof is easy: Write $f(n) = n^{n^{-p}}$. Then
$$\log f(n) = n^{-p}\log n,$$
$$\log \log f(n) = -p \log(n) + \log \log n \sim -p \log(n),$$
$$\log f(n) = n^{-p + o(1)},$$
$$f(n) = \exp(n^{-p + o(1)}) \to 1.$$

Does "$\sim$" and "$o(1)$" mean "approximate to" and "function that converges to 0", respectively? If so, I don't understand why one can disregard $\log \log n$, since it diverges to infinity. Can you think of a more elementary approach without log or exp? Thank you for the answer, nonetheless.

$a(n) = o(1)$ means $a(n) \to 0$. And $a(n) \sim b(n)$ means $\frac{a(n)}{b(n)} \to 1$, or equivalently, $a(n) = b(n)(1 + o(1))$.

How can you define $n^{-p}$ for all real $p$ in an elementary way? This is equivalent to defining $\exp$. Then $\log$ is just the inverse of $\exp$.

Rudin defines $b^r := \sup B(r)$ where $B(r) := \left {b^t \mid t \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge t \leq r  \right }$.

@Bool Well, it's easy to show that $b^r = \exp(r \log b)$ for $r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, \infty)$, and from the definition, this also holds for $r \in \mathbb{R} \cap (0, \infty)$.
